# How to write the contrapositive of this statement..?

Tags: irrational-numbers

"There is $x \in \mathbb{Q}$ such that $x+y \notin \mathbb{Q}$ implies $y \notin \mathbb{Q}$."

Would it be "$y \in \mathbb{Q}$ implies there is $x \in \mathbb{Q}$ such that $x+y \in \mathbb{Q}$"?

..or an $x \notin \mathbb{Q}$?

Answer (score 0):

Neither.  It would be:  If $y$ is rational there is *NOT* a rational number $x$ where $x + y$ is irrational.

Or you could alternatively state it as: If $y$ is rational and $x$ is rational then $x + y$ is rational.

Comment: so what would the contrapositive of "there exists an integer n such that ny is irrational => y is irrational" be? i think i've done this all wrong |:(

Comment: If $y$ is rational than then there does NOT exist an integer $n$ so that $ny$ is irrational.  Or in other words.  If $y$ is rational then for all integers $n$ we have $ny$ is rational.